# How to delete unknown user profiles remotely?

Tags: windows-7, windows, performance, active-directory

When user is deleted from Active Directory, it shows as an unknown user.
System properties -> Advanced -> User Profile -> Settings...

I have to delete it manually all the time.

There are more than 400 workstations in my domain, the attrition rate is very high in my company. My system contains only the C drive. If that data is not deleted, does it make the system slow? There is heavy software which is running all the time. Would it make any difference in my performance if I deleted it?

Comment: Contact your IT department with regards on how to do this.  You will be unable to delete this profile unless you have **domain** `Administrator` permissions

Answer (score 3):

You could also use a Powershell script that deletes profiles of user's that haven't logged into a workstation in a certain length of time, say 30 or 90+ days, etc.

Essentially, you want to use something like

```
#Get user names that have logged onto workstation
$Users = gwmi win32_networkloginprofile | where {$_.name -match "DomainName\\"} | where {$_.name -notmatch "srvtasksched"}

#For each user, delete if they haven't logged into the workstation in over 2 weeks
$Users | foreach{

    $Name = $_.Name
    $LastLogon = $_.LastLogon

    $LogonTime = [System.datetime]::ParseExact($LastLogon.Substring(0, $LastLogon.IndexOf(".")), "yyyyMMddHHmmss", [System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo]::InvariantInfo)

    if($(Get-Date).Subtract($LogonTime).TotalDays -ge 14)
    {
        #User hasn't logged into workstation in over 2 weeks
        #Get profile path
        $UserSID = $(New-Object System.Security.Principal.NTAccount($Name)).Translate([System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier]).Value
        $UserRegKey = GCI 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList' | where {$_.Name -match $UserSID}

        $ProfilePath = $(Get-ItemProperty $UserRegKey.PSPath -Name ProfileImagePath).ProfileImagePath

        Write-Host "Deleting User $Name"
        gwmi win32_userprofile | where {$_.SID -eq $UserSID} | foreach {$_.Delete()}

    }
```

I was feeling generous, so you can drop that script in and pretty much run it, updating the domain name and the number of days since last logon.

As for the remote part, you want to set your environment up for powershell remoting, use the  `Invoke-Command` cmdlet, and paste this script after the script block parameter

`-ScriptBlock {script here}`

Answer (score 0):

Consider using delprof2: http://helgeklein.com/free-tools/delprof2-user-profile-deletion-tool/

All it needs to run remotely is the 'remote registry' setting, and you can have it purge out all currently-unused profiles (or profiles over a certain age), including registry settings. I believe it works fine on unknowns, but this would certainly be my first step. Once you have remote registry set up, you can then run delprof2 from a batch file across your entire site.